# Mainsail OS booted with Read Only File System

Tags: filesystem

I have an install of mainsail running on my Raspberry Pi 3B+, and the nginx is unable to start because the file system is in read only mode.

How can I fix this so I have a writeable filesystem?

Here is what I've looked at and tried:

Logs for the nginx service:

```
$ systemctl status nginx.service
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-12-26 21:09:58 EST; 1min 0s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 568 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 108ms

Dec 26 21:09:54 endersgame2 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 26 21:09:55 endersgame2 nginx[568]: nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (30: Read-only file system)
Dec 26 21:09:58 endersgame2 nginx[568]: 2023/12/26 21:09:55 [emerg] 568#568: open() "/var/log/nginx/access.log" failed (30: Read-only file system)
Dec 26 21:09:58 endersgame2 nginx[568]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Dec 26 21:09:58 endersgame2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 26 21:09:58 endersgame2 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 26 21:09:58 endersgame2 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

/etc/fstab

```
$ more /etc/fstab
proc   "        /proc       $`  proc    defaults          0      0
PARTUUID}d(437f2c-01  +boot           vfat    defaults         0       2
PARTUUID=d8437f2a-02  /              ext4    defaults,noatime  0�      1
# a swapfile is not"a swap partition, no |ine here
#   tse  dphys-swapfile swapZon|off]  for that
```

lsblk

```
$ lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE FSVER LABEL  UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat   FAT32 bootfs 9E81-4F92
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4   1.0   rootfs cf2895ca-6dc2-4797-8040-f76ba1508f41   21.8G    19% /
```

I tried to remount and received this:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
[sudo] password for rquackenbush:
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 1 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 2 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 3 -- ignored
```

subset of dmesg:

```
[    3.587842] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=d8437f2c-02...
[    3.625726] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    3.635566] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[    3.642799] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SPCC  29.0 GiB
[    3.658914]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    3.665971] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SPCC  29.0 GiB
[    3.675933] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    3.700874] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[    3.707284] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
```

mount:

```
$ mount
/dev/mmcblk0p2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=297832k,nr_inodes=74458,mode=755)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,size=171768k,nr_inodes=819200,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=30,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=85880k,nr_inodes=21470,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Comment: If what you listed is the actual contents of fstab your filesystem is corrupted. It MAY be possible to repair but most of us would restore from a backup (preferably to a new SD Card)

Comment: @Milliways - thanks. That's what I was afraid of but I was hoping for a second set of eyes. In my case, I had the critical data backed up so I just did a fresh install on a new SD card.